# Convert Python 'min:sec' string into a time object that looks the same, needs to be sorted properly by jQuery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, time, tablesorter

For some reason, tablesorter works properly only on strings that represents time lower than '25:00'. It's putting anything above '25:00' lower than '24:12' or '09:24' for example. So I probably need to convert the string to a time format. To be able to use `col-index: { sorter: 'time'}` in the tablesorter.

This is how it looks now

[image: This is how it looks now]

I've read datetime and time docs, found some great answers on SO, but couldn't find exactly what I need.

The closest I get is:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('12:55', '%M:%S')

print(datetime_object)

>>> 1900-01-01 00:12:55
```

Comment: Can you not simply split it, by `:`, and then `split[0] * 60 + split[1]`?  If it's not a datetime then don't try to make it a datetime.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to sort on the time? Then you can sort on the unix time of each event?

dateEvent = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeEvent, "%M:%S")
,unix = time.mktime(dateEvent.timetuple())

Comment: @Kspr I want to sort a time that I am getting from an NHL API. This is a hockey players time on ice per game.

Comment: How about using re to split the string at the : symbol and store in hour and second variable?

Comment: @Archer you mean, I need to do this in JS, not in Python, right?

Comment: No - that was an example of the theory.  You're not working with a date time - you're working with a time period, so just treat it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), there is an additional [countdown parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-duration.js#L39-L65). Load the `parser-duration.js` file and set the sorter to "countdown".

Answer (score -1):

time() method is used to get only time from the given datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('12:55', '%M:%S').time()
print(str(datetime_object)[3:])
```

output:

> 12:55

Comment: you can do it with slicing (see edited code), if answer helps you then click on accept.

Comment: it will be a string again, so there is no point. You couldn't slice the datetime object, I believe.

Comment: I don't think you can change the representation of object itself however you can extract hour minute and second as integers.

Comment: From a datetime object you can try using datetime_object.hour

Comment: But it will return an integer representing hour, minute or second what he wants is representing datetime object with only minute two values, which  i guess is not possible. @Kspr